# Implementing a Retweet function with an existing Tweet model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, model

I am trying to implement a retweet (repost) function for a Twitter clone. I initially thought I might need a separate retweet model, but I want to try and implement it using my existing tweet (micropost) model.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the schema and what migrations I would need to run. A Micropost would need a Repost column, but would a user need a repost_id? So I would add a Repost column to Micropost, and it would reference User? Or should I actually be adding the column to the User model?

Also if the repost function would work similar to create, would it not?

```
  def repost
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    @repost = @micropost.repost by current_user
    if @repost.save
      flash[:success] = "Repost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

Is there any way to edit my current Micropost model, or do I need to utilize a specific Repost model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I go about is asking if I need a one to many or a many to many relationship between reposts and users. A user can have (make) many reposts and a repost can be reposted by many users, so that would be a many to many relationship. Meaning you need a joint table between users and micropost - and the optimal name for it in this case is repost.

If you want to think about it the other way round - the way you proposed it: if you would reference the user id in the micropost table in a user_id column, there wouldonly be "enough space" to save one user id... so that would be a one to many association, which doesn't make that much sense for reposts.

For your question about the method, you will need to create a new repost instance once a user clicks on a button (submits a form) to repost. You should have a look at nested resources: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources